# jQuery UI AutoComplete - not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm getting this error, and can't figure out why.

**TypeError: Result of expression '$('#schedule_person_person_name').autocomplete' [undefined] is not a function.**

Here's the relevant code from my HTML:

```
<script src="/javascripts/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schedule_person_person_name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm fairly confident that jQuery UI is being loaded, as when I inspect it in Safari I can browse the code on the Resources tab.

If I change the line of code to:

```
$('#schedule_person_person_name').css('background-color', 'red');
```

... the background turns red, so I know the selector is working.

I'm about ready to punch my screen, because nothing seems wrong, so I'm starting to wonder if my brain is just not seeing it correctly anymore. Stupid brain.

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4ndfh/1/) work is safari?

Comment: Yep! It works fine. That's what's driving me nuts -- demos all seem to work, but my code doesn't, and I can't see any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be some kind of conflict with jQuery Tools. I've done a custom build that includes just what I wanted (the tooltips), and that resolved the problem. Weird.

Comment: I've seen the same thing recently. If you do a custom name instead of $ that should also fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seems to have the autocomplte.js . Add this into your script or download it to your static diretly

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Comment: Autocomplete is included in the jquery-ui.min.js. I've even searched within the minified code and sure enough, the autocomplete is there.

Comment: Additionally, while I wasn't able to link to that file directly (403 forbidden), I saved it and added it to my project, and still get the same error.